# How to implement 'others' in django models choices-charfield

Tags: python, django, django-forms

was wondering if anyone here know of a good implementation for 'others' choice (where user can input custom text) in django models multi-select .... say for instance i have a multiple choice model field 'options' with pre-set a and b choices.

```
options = models.CharField (
    max_length=2,
    choices=[(a,'a'), (b,'b')],
    default=a,
)
```

What if I want the user to be able to select a choice 'others' and thereon key in his custom text i.e. 'd' The only way I can think of really, is to use a different field , say options_custom (without getting into the specifics of the model etc...the dummy snippet below is just for discussion sake)

```
options = models.CharField (
    max_length=2,
    choices=[(a,'a'), (b,'b'), ('others', 'others')],
    default=a,
)

# added this..
options_custom = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, verbose_name="Input custom text here" )

# and put a conditional... if others then return options_custom
if choices == 'others':
    return options_custom  # something like this....
```

What do you think? I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Yes, I need to know this too